# When adding d3.behavior.zoom, the .on("zoom", zoom), zoom undefined

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am having one hell of a time with learning how to zoom. To learn, I have been trying to make a dendrogram zoom. I am taking this jsfiddle example (http://jsfiddle.net/6kEpp/1/) and trying to apply it to a dendrogram that does not have collapsing nodes. I took this dendrogram from the radial dendrogram example by Bostock and straightened it out.

I apologize for adding the entire script.

When debugging, I am told that zoom is not defined in ".on("zoom", zoom));". I have seen examples that do not define a var zoom.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 2000 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 2000 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, width])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, height])
    .range([height, 0]);

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width])
    .separation(function(a, b) { return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 2) / a.depth; });

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom()
        .x(x)
        .y(y)
        .scaleExtent([1,8])
        .on("zoom", zoom));


d3.json("flare.json", function(error, root) {
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(links)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5);

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".31em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  // zoom in / out
function zoom(d) {
        var nodes = svg.selectAll(".node");
        nodes.attr("transform", transform);

        // Update the links...
        var link = svg.selectAll(".link");
        link.attr("d", translate);

    }

    function transform(d) {
        return "translate(" + x(d.y) + "," + y(d.x) + ")";
    }

    function translate(d) {
        var sourceX = x(d.target.parent.y);
        var sourceY = y(d.target.parent.x);
        var targetX = x(d.target.y);
        var targetY = (sourceX + targetX)/2;
        var linkTargetY = y(d.target.x0);
        var result = "M"+sourceX+","+sourceY+" C"+targetX+","+sourceY+" "+targetY+","+y(d.target.x0)+" "+targetX+","+linkTargetY+"";
        //console.log(result);

       return result;
    }
});

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `zoom()` is defined inside the function `d3.json()`, thus you cannot use it outside.

As you probably need to use this function inside `d3.json()`, I would recommend you to also call it from inside this function:

```
...
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

d3.json("flare.json", function(error, root) {
    svg.call(d3.behavior.zoom()
        .x(x)
        .y(y)
        .scaleExtent([1,8])
        .on("zoom", zoom));
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root),
        links = tree.links(nodes);
    ....
    function zoom(d){ ... }
    ...
})
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
```

opening tag needed, specially if you close `</html>` later in you script.
try to change you javascript layout, put your `function zoom(d)` on top so the variable definition can depend on it if zoom is called. also remember if you specify a value in a function like `(d)` you need to call it the same

```
var d =  ;// ??

..().().().on("zoom", zoom(d)));
```

otherwise specify what to do if `d` is not given at the function call.
you could ask for existing `d` in your function like

```
function zoom(){
  var d=arguments[0] || 'bar';
  console.log(d);
}
zoom('foo'); // 'foo'
zoom(); // 'bar'
```